# Is it valid to create a ByteArrayInputStream from a local variable?

Tags: java, variables, garbage-collection, inputstream, local

Suppose a function like:

```
InputStream func() {            
       byte[] buffer = new byte[] {0,1,2,3};

       return new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);
}
```

if I call that function, is there a possibility that the garbage collector deletes the 'buffer' variable and the InputStream doesn't work anymore?

Comment: If it does it's a bad garbage collector, since that `ByteArrayInputStream` is still referencing the array.

Comment: No, that is a fine factory like creation of something. Everything in java lives on the heap. The array object's "address" is placed in the local stack variable `buffer`, but just the "address" is returned. The same as for results, goes for parameters: a variable as parameter will never gets its value (the address) changed, as the address is passed.

Comment: It’s always funny how learning about the existence of a “you don't need to worry about memory” garbage collector causes people to worry about it (given the amount of “will the garbage collector break this” questions). The answer is, of course, it will not “delete” the buffer when it is in use. By the way, you can also use the shorter array allocation syntax: `byte[] buffer = {0,1,2,3};`, the result will be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a possibility that the garbage collector deletes the 'buffer'
>   variable and the InputStream doesn't work anymore?

No, the garbage collector is not allowed to remove objects which are still referenced. The object is referenced from within the `ByteArrayInputStream` object (its interal `buf` member references that object).

Comment: Edited your answer so it's more clear. Because "No" in response to the question title and question body are contradictory :)

Comment: @Michael Yeah, saw that problem after posting the answer, too. Thanks for this good solution!

Answer (score 0):

If you will see the constructor of ByteArrayInputStream you will see following

```
 public ByteArrayInputStream(byte buf[]) {
        this.buf = buf;
        this.pos = 0;
        this.count = buf.length;
    }
```

So as you can see the reference to byte array is stored in InputStream object: this.buf = buf . And GC will not collect an object which has a strong reference. So nothing to worry about.